# Multipe radio buttons groups

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this form:

```
<div id="div1">
  <form>
  <input type="radio" name="r1" id="r1" value="r1 value 1" />
  <input type="radio" name="r1" id="r1" value="r1 value 2" />
  <input type="radio" name="r1" id="r1" value="r1 value 3" />

  <input type="radio" name="r2" id="r2" value="r2 value 1" />
  <input type="radio" name="r2" id="r2" value="r2 value 2" />
  <input type="radio" name="r2" id="r2" value="r2 value 3" />

  <input type="radio" name="r3" id="r3" value="r3 value 1" />
  <input type="radio" name="r3" id="r3" value="r3 value 2" />
  <input type="radio" name="r3" id="r3" value="r3 value 3" />
  </form>
</div>
```

The number of radio button groups is changeable.

How do I **deselect** any other radio button once the end user selects any radio button in a certain group, because currently if I select `r1` value 1 and then select `r3` value 3, both of them will be ticked. I want it once I select a radio button within a certain group to deselect radio buttons across all other groups beside the one that I have the selection on.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Give them all the same name - that's how radio buttons are supposed to work.

Comment: First problem you have is that [IDs need to be unique](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2), you are using the same ones multiple times

Comment: @Xotic750 - That's not really the problem.  The grouping is based on name.  It's not valid HTML, but, that won't solve his problem.

Comment: i want to keep them with different IDs for another need on the page.

Comment: @AhmedElGamil do you know [`document.getElementsByTagName(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName)? There should be no need for multiple elements with the same ID.

Comment: @kay and how to dedicate that to be generic and ready for any changes that can be done later on the page. i dont want to change it manually all the time?

Comment: Obviously you have something in mind that you have not disclosed to us, but this is causing you the problem that you have posted. Show us the full picture as to why you want to break radio input grouping design, and why you want to use multiple IDs that breaks the W3C design. Perhaps someone can then give you a possible solution. Perhaps [`data-` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through jQuery, what you're asking for is most definitely possible. Here is the exact solution:

```
$('#div1 form input:radio').change(function() {
  // Grabs all other radio buttons in the form, and
  // deselects all but the one which was clicked on.
  $('#div1 form input:radio').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

In addition, IDs have to be 100% unique between any HTML element. While this doesn't prevent the above code from working, if you were to attempt select an item based on it's ID such as `$('#r1')`  only one of those elements will be returned, not all of them.

For a full implementation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#div1 form input:radio').change(function() {
                    // Grabs all other radio buttons in the form, and
                    // deselects all but the one which was clicked on.
                    $('#div1 form input:radio').not(this).prop('checked', false);
                });
            });
        </script>

        <div id="div1">
            <form>
                <input type="radio" name="r1" id="r1" value="r1 value 1" />
                <input type="radio" name="r1" id="r1" value="r1 value 2" />
                <input type="radio" name="r1" id="r1" value="r1 value 3" />

                <input type="radio" name="r2" id="r2" value="r2 value 1" />
                <input type="radio" name="r2" id="r2" value="r2 value 2" />
                <input type="radio" name="r2" id="r2" value="r2 value 3" />

                <input type="radio" name="r3" id="r3" value="r3 value 1" />
                <input type="radio" name="r3" id="r3" value="r3 value 2" />
                <input type="radio" name="r3" id="r3" value="r3 value 3" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

For IE 6, 7 and 8 compatibility:

```
Replace:
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
With:
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: tested , working on Firefox / chrome .. but not with IE for some reason ?

Comment: Not working in ie? I'll look into it more and update you in a min.

Comment: what version of ie are you testing it in? works in 10, don't have access to any other version right now...

Comment: the mighty IE8 that i hope the company get rid off one day.

Comment: if you're copying and pasting my exact example, replace the existing script tag with: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>` ... jQuery 2 doesn't support ie 6, 7 or 8 while version 1 does. let me know if that fixes it.

Comment: glad i could help! ps i upvoted your question so now you're sitting at a comfortably at 0. there are some haters out there. learning how to ask the right question is part of learning how to program. people also knit pick way too much.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31982/discussion-between-ahmed-elgamil-and-joshua-burns)

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason all the radio buttons can't be in the same group?  Putting them under the same group name is an easy fix.  If not, using a simple jQuery click handler to deselect all other radio buttons will work.

Also, you have duplicate IDs in your example.  Not sure if that's intended or a mistake, but you should fix that also.

Comment: i need them to stay as different IDs. i have tried some javascript functions to deselect other radio buttons but i have to enter the id names manually . i want it to be done regardless the changes that might take a place later within the page.

Answer (score 1):

This way you have your groups.
But as soon you select another radio it deselects any other radio.
id's,name's changed.

```
<div id="div1">
  <form>
<div>Group 1
  <input type="radio" name="r" id="g1r1" value="r1 value 1" />
  <input type="radio" name="r" id="g1r2" value="r1 value 2" />
  <input type="radio" name="r" id="g1r3" value="r1 value 3" />
</div>
<div>Group 2
  <input type="radio" name="r" id="g2r1" value="r2 value 1" />
  <input type="radio" name="r" id="g2r2" value="r2 value 2" />
  <input type="radio" name="r" id="g2r3" value="r2 value 3" />
</div>
<div>Group 3
  <input type="radio" name="r" id="g3r1" value="r3 value 1" />
  <input type="radio" name="r" id="g3r2" value="r3 value 2" />
  <input type="radio" name="r" id="g3r3" value="r3 value 3" />
</div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: name has to be different for each group as will be assigned a value on submit.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code so that the name attribute for all the radio buttons are the same. And you can't have same id for more than one element.